# Оператор return в блоке try/except/finally

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, return

Имеется такая функция:

```
def f():
    try:
        1 / 0
    except:
        return 1
    finally:
        return 2
    return 3
```

При запуске она возвращает `2`, хотя после возникновения исключения должна попадать в блок  `except`, где возвращается `1`, разве `return` не прерывает выполнение функции?

Comment: Вопрос конечно интересный, но я бы не сказал, что прямо часто задаваемый. Поэтому метку python-faq убираю.

Comment: @insolor по поводу python-faq согласен, а зачем убрали return? Вопрос в целом по работе этого оператора, тут скорее логично тогда тег исключения убирать

Comment: Ну по return в принципе можно было и оставить, в данном случае она вполне релевантна. Часто подобные метки (типа while, for, return) добавляют просто потому что эти ключевые слова в коде есть, так точно делать не нужно. Тут удалил скорее по инерции.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**: блок внутри `finally` выполнится **в любом случае**, независимо от того, что происходит внутри блоков `try, except, else`, поэтому вернется значение `2`.

---

### Если углубиться:

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions), когда внутри блоков `try/except/else` встречается оператор `return`, а после есть оператор `finally`, то выполнение функции не прерывается, а происходит примерно следующее:

1. Возвращаемое значение запоминается (но не возвращается), далее поток выполнения переходит к блоку `finally`.
2. Внутри блока `finally` выполняются все действия, после чего возвращается ранее запомненное значение.
3. В случае же, если внутри блока `finally` содержится свой `return`, то он перезаписывает прошлое значение и возвращает его, забывая обо всем, что было раньше.

Но, важно упомянуть, что "запоминание" возвращаемого результата происходит путем копирования его значения в другую переменную (и последующего замыкания), и тут, как и в любой другой ситуации, играет роль **тип** объекта: **изменяемый**, или **неизменяемый**.

Посмотрим на код ниже:

```
def f():
    try:
        a = 2
        return a
    finally:
        a += 1
```

В результате выполнения - функция вернет `2`, поскольку числа в языке `Python` - **неизменяемые** объекты, операция `+=` создает **новый** объект, который никак не влияет на значение, скопированное для возврата через `return`.

Но, изменим ситуацию:

```
def f():
    try:
        a = [2]
        return a
    finally:
        a[0] += 1
```

Уже здесь - вернется список `[3]`, потому что значение было изменено **по ссылке**.

Так происходит, потому что списки - это **изменяемые** объекты и в результате операций с ними возвращается **тот же самый** объект.

---

### Такое поведение только у оператора return?

Вообще, такое прерывание выполнения и переход к блоку `finally` происходит не только с оператором `return`, но и при возникновении любого исключения, и много чего еще, например, вызова `sys.exit()` (который, на самом деле, тоже вызывает исключение).

Убедимся в этом:

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception
    finally:
        return 1
```

В результате работы функции никакого исключения **не возникнет** и будет возвращено `1`.

И, если задуматься, то это большая проблема, мы никогда не узнаем о том исключении, которое у нас возникло, вследствие возврата значения в блоке `finally`.

Поэтому, в руководстве по написанию кода `PEP 8` есть специальный раздел, в котором написано, что не рекомендуется использовать `return` в блоке `finally`, поэтому: знать о том, как это работает - полезно, но применять - не стоит.

> Use of the flow control statements `return/break/continue` within the
> `finally` suite of a `try...finally`, where the flow control statement
> would jump outside the `finally` suite, is discouraged. This is because
> such statements will implicitly cancel any active exception that is
> propagating through the `finally` suite.

---

Однако, в случае, если изначально было выброшено необработанное исключение, а в блоке `finally` выбрасывается еще одно, тогда будут выведены они оба.

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception
    finally:
        raise TypeError
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

---

### Выводы:

Обобщив все вышесказанное, можно понять, что:

Оператор `finally` выполняется **всегда**, и выполняется он в **последнюю** очередь, поэтому, если в блоке `try-except-else` встретится какая-либо исключительная ситуация (возврат значения, исключение, операторы прерывания), то код в блоке `finally` может повлиять на них (в случае возникновения **новой** исключительной ситуации).

Но, естественно, это относится к только одному цельному блоку (`try-except-else-finally`), и если бы мы слегка изменили исходный пример:

```
def f():
    return 3
    try:
        1 / 0
    except:
        return 1
    finally:
        return 2
```

То, конечно, функция уже вернет `3`, потому что до блока исключений она не успеет дойти, после вызова `return` ее выполнение **прервется**.

Такое поведение используется только с оператором `finally`, и, например, в случае:

```
def f():
    try:
        return 1
    except:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

Несмотря на то, что ошибок в блоке `try` нет - блок `else` **не выполнится**, и будет возвращено значение `1`, потому что отсутствует оператор `finally`, вследствие чего ожидаемое поведение с прерыванием работы **не меняется**.

---

### Дополнительно

Функционал с гарантированным выполнением блока `finally` используется неявно и при использовании контекстного менеджера `with`, именно поэтому его часто рекомендуют в использовании: что бы ни происходило внутри блока `with` - операция закрытия файла/соединения будет произведена.